# What are ways to constantly wait for an array to be empty, and emit an event once it is empty it NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I have a system for workers that stores when a worker is running into an array. If the array has length, there are workers. If it has no length, no workers. At the moment it has no length, I want an event to be emitted. My current event emitter basically works like this

ScriptThatNeedsEmitter.js

```
const eventEmitter = require('./eventEmitter');

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //Run code in here
    eventEmitter.once('WORK_DONE', () => {
        resolve('success');
    });
});

fileWrite.on('end', () => {
    eventEmitter.emit("WORK_DONE");
}
```

eventEmitter.js

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
module.exports = new EventEmitter();
```

The only issue here is that some workers are still running their code and processing data after the fileWrite is done, causing writeAfterEnd issues and such, and missing some data. How can I make the emit only happen when the worker array is empty, as just doing

```
if (array.length = 0) {
    eventEmitter.emit("WORK_DONE");
}
```

Means it just won't fire since the worker array isn't empty, and it then never emits

Comment: First thought would be to make an Observable composed of the array, and subscribe to it.  Any time it changes, your subscription would evaluate if it was empty to know to do something.

Comment: What is an observable? And can I make it without extra packages. My system at work requires a bit of time before packages can be approved to use

Comment: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/rxjs-observables-observers-operators  Random google, referencing the Rxjs implementation of Observables as that's the one I'm familiar with.

Comment: So I'd need to add RxJS to this, which can take like two weeks